# Can I use my Nintendo Network ID on my Nintendo DS Lite?

Tags: nintendo-ds

Is there any way I can use my Network ID on my DS? I want to use the eShop and get Nintendo friends. I also want to sync my Nintendo Switch eShop game data with my DS. Also, I would like to use themes. Last but not least, my Nintendo Points.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. The Nintendo DS, DS Lite, and DSi only had limited support for Internet functionality, and most of that functionality has been shut down.

The Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection service, which allowed online play for certain games, [was discontinued in May 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20190402101716/https://www.nintendo.com/whatsnew/detail/vyWpoM6CBIe6FjW8NIY7bvzOrgBURhzw).

The Nintendo DSi Shop [was closed in April 2017](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4479/~/nintendo-dsi-shop-overview).

Answer (score 0):

**You can transfer your Network Id on your Nintendo DS Lite.**

---

#### How to Transfer Your Network Id

From [Nintendo Support](https://support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1318/~/can-i-log-into-my-nintendo-network-id-on-a-different-console%3F), here is the message they tell you about connecting your Network Id:

> A Nintendo Network ID can only be transferred to a different console by using the built-in system transfer process or if it is removed from the original system by Nintendo (for example, if the system was exchanged during a repair).

So, in short words, you can transfer it if it's:

- Removed from the regular system (not recommended, I think you want to use it on your regular as well)
- Build-in system transfer process

**NOTE:**  From Nintendo, 3DS online servers will be shutting down.

---